# How I can make module connecting to external REST api?

Tags: django

I am doing simple app which has to connect to external REST api, get data in json and print it for the user. My questions are:

1. Where should I put/create a module which will connect to external REST api? I mean I could just write some code in views.py which connects to REST api and the passes the results to template but I want to separate it in some autonomic module which I could use in views.py like `myapimodule.get_devices()` which for example will connect and get data from example.com/api/device/get. I tried python and django for first time today so I just want to know where u put (and how) such modules in django app?
2. How I can connect to RESTAPI with django? I have for example username and password for http auth and address like example.com/api/device/get - what parts of django lib will allow me to use the restapi and retrieve data from it (in json format)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There's really no "right" answer. It just depends on what's best for your needs.
2. To connect to an external REST API, take a look at the excellent [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library.

Comment: This Requests lib doesnt work - I tried downloading it from git repo, then I put `requests` folder in my app folder and tried `import requests` in my view - there is error `cannot import name chardet`. I looked in google and it seems that it is known problem but everywhere it applies to python 3 and I am using python 2.7 - can't find solution to this - any clues?

Comment: We use requests every day at my work, installed via pip into our virtualenv(s).

Comment: This will slow down the whole application, for every request blocks the whole process.

Comment: @bryanph The user never specified whether he was connecting synchronously or asynchronously, they asked how they could connect in general.

Answer (score 0):

The Requests library is worth learning. It will save you a lot of grief.

Did you try:

```
pip install chardet
```

before

```
pip install requests
```

?